# Holding document.Ready() sometime with jquery holdReady function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am facing an issue with jquery holdReady .

```
 $.holdReady(true);
    $.getScript("someXJqueryPlugin.js", function() {
    $.holdReady(false);
    });
```

In my ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 someFunctionFromMyPlugin();
});
```

Because of `someXJqueryPlugin.js`  is some what bigger in size .So i am trying to delay the the ready function untill my plugin loaded.

Still iam getting the error  someFunctionFromMyPlugin  not a function .

Any hints ??What I am missing ?? please help .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cross checked with my path of js .its correct .

Comment: This depends heavily on your code. Most likely the ready event has already fired. You need to call holdready asap, the best would be directly in the head.

Comment: @Christoph  ok.Let me give a try .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest placing the document ready inside of the done callback.

```
$.getScript(url,function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

or using deferreds:

```
$.when( $.getScript(url), $.ready ).done(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

*Note* `$.ready` is not documented and is subject to change, you can replace it with the following for a more stable version:

```
$.when( $.getScript(url), $.Deferred(function(def){
    $(def.resolve);
})).done(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: @TheSureshAtta Sure, it would work, it should work the way you have it. However, i suspect something else is interfering with it. All three of the ways in my answer are self contained, meaning external factors won't affect how it operates (such as something else using `holdReady`)